# how can i combine three mongodb query into single query

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have three collections as follows :

```
db={
  "category": [
    {
      "_id": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
      "name": "Cat A",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": "6492fd9251feab2f2485a581",
      "name": "Cat B",
      
    }
  ],
  "subcategory": [
    {
      "_id": "64841e2380a7a74a913b7943",
      "name": "Sub Cat A",
      "categoryId": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": "64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de",
      "name": "Sub Cat B",
      "categoryId": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": "6492d31581c81e578307c1f1",
      "name": "Sub Cat C",
      "categoryId": "6492fd9251feab2f2485a581",
      
    }
  ],
  "store": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "Store A",
      "categoryId": "6492fd9251feab2f2485a581",
      "subCategoryId": "64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "Store B",
      "categoryId": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
      "subCategoryId": "64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "Store C",
      "categoryId": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
      "subCategoryId": "64841e2380a7a74a913b7943",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "name": "Store D",
      "categoryId": "6492fd9251feab2f2485a581",
      "subCategoryId": "64841e2380a7a74a913b7943",
      
    },
    {
      "_id": 5,
      "name": "Store E",
      "categoryId": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
      "subCatgeoryId": "6492d31581c81e578307c1f1"
    },
    
  ]
}
```

currently i am using three different mongodb queries to fetch data, how can i combine three queries to get a the below response.

```
{
  "category": [
    {
      "_id": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
      "name": "Cat A",
      "subcategory" : [
        {
          "_id": "64841e2380a7a74a913b7943",
          "name": "Sub Cat A",
          "categoryId": {
            "_id": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
            "name": "Cat A",
          },
          
        },
        {
          "_id": "64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de",
          "name": "Sub Cat B",
          "categoryId": {
            "_id": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
            "name": "Cat A",
          }
          
        }
      ],
      "store": [
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "name": "Store B",
            "categoryId": "categoryId": {
              "_id": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
              "name": "Cat A",
            }
            "subCategoryId": {
              "_id": "64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de",
              "name": "Sub Cat B",
            },
            
          },
          {
            "_id": 3,
            "name": "Store C",
            "categoryId": "categoryId": {
              "_id": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
              "name": "Cat A",
            }
            "subCategoryId": {
              "_id": "64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de",
              "name": "Sub Cat B",
            }
            
          },
          {
            "_id": 5,
            "name": "Store E",
            "categoryId": "categoryId": {
              "_id": "64841d0280a7a74a913b7935",
              "name": "Cat A",
            }
            "subCategoryId": {
              "_id": "64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de",
              "name": "Sub Cat B",
            }
          },
        ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "6492fd9251feab2f2485a581",
      "name": "Cat B",
      "subcategory": [
        {
          "_id": "6492d31581c81e578307c1f1",
          "name": "Sub Cat C",
          "categoryId": {
            "_id": "6492fd9251feab2f2485a581",
            "name": "Cat B",
          },
        }
      ],
      "store": [
        {
          "_id": 1,
          "name": "Store A",
          "categoryId": {
            "_id": "6492fd9251feab2f2485a581",
            "name": "Cat B",
          },
          "subCategoryId": {
            "_id": "64841e2380a7a74a913b7943",
            "name": "Sub Cat A",
          },
          
        },
        {
          "_id": 4,
          "name": "Store D",
          "categoryId": {
            "_id": "6492fd9251feab2f2485a581",
            "name": "Cat B",
          },
          "subCategoryId": {
            "_id": "64841e2380a7a74a913b7943",
            "name": "Sub Cat A",
          },
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As of now i am saving the response of first query in a variable, then using a map iterator on it to query data from second collection and so on.

**current queries : **

```
data_1 = await schema_1.find()
data_1.map((doc) => {
  data_2 = await schema_2.find({ categoryId: doc._id })
})
data_2.map((doc) => {
  data_3 = await schema_2.find({ subCategoryId: doc._id })
})
```

Comment: I think you probably want `$lookup`, but it would be more clear if you shared your current code/queries with us

Comment: @user20042973 i have updated my question with current queries.

Answer (score 0):

A double `$lookup` will yield you want you need with multiple docs, one for each `category`.  The result also avoids all the duping of parent (containing) structure data in your desired target output:

```
db.fooCat.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {"from": "fooSubCat",
               let: { cid: "$_id" },
               pipeline: [
                   {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$categoryId", "$$cid" ]} }},
               ],
               as: "subcategory"
              }},

    {$lookup: {"from": "fooStore",
               let: { cid: "$_id" },
               pipeline: [
                   {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$categoryId", "$$cid" ]} }},
               ],
               as: "store"
              }}
]);
```

```
{
  _id: '64841d0280a7a74a913b7935',
  name: 'Cat A',
  subcategory: [
    {
      _id: '64841e2380a7a74a913b7943',
      name: 'Sub Cat A',
      categoryId: '64841d0280a7a74a913b7935'
    },
    {
      _id: '64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de',
      name: 'Sub Cat B',
      categoryId: '64841d0280a7a74a913b7935'
    }
  ],
  store: [
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'Store B',
      categoryId: '64841d0280a7a74a913b7935',
      subCategoryId: '64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de'
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: 'Store C',
      categoryId: '64841d0280a7a74a913b7935',
      subCategoryId: '64841e2380a7a74a913b7943'
    },
    {
      _id: 5,
      name: 'Store E',
      categoryId: '64841d0280a7a74a913b7935',
      subCatgeoryId: '6492d31581c81e578307c1f1'
    }
  ]
}
{
  _id: '6492fd9251feab2f2485a581',
  name: 'Cat B',
  subcategory: [
    {
      _id: '6492d31581c81e578307c1f1',
      name: 'Sub Cat C',
      categoryId: '6492fd9251feab2f2485a581'
    }
  ],
  store: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'Store A',
      categoryId: '6492fd9251feab2f2485a581',
      subCategoryId: '64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de'
    },
    {
      _id: 4,
      name: 'Store D',
      categoryId: '6492fd9251feab2f2485a581',
      subCategoryId: '64841e2380a7a74a913b7943'
    }
  ]
}
```

If you really want a single doc with an array of `category`, then add this to the pipeline after the second `$lookup`:

```
    {$group: {'_id':null, category: {$push: '$$ROOT'}}}
```

### ALTERNATE APPROACH

Since the `store` collection seems to have all the `category` and `subcategory` keys anyway, if you can "trust it" and do not require other information from the other collections, and are OK with category values assigned to `_id`, you can bypass doing `lookup` completely and simply "reform" the store data thusly using the double `$group`-and-push trick:

```js
c = db.fooStore.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {cid:'$categoryId',scid:'$subCategoryId'}, store: {$push: {_id:'$_id',name:'$name'}} }}

    ,{$group: {_id: '$_id.cid', subcat: {$push: '$_id.scid'}, store: {$push: '$store'}}}

    /*                                                                                                      
    At this point 'store' is an array of arrays, e.g.                                                       
                                                                                                            
  store: [                                                                                                  
    [ { _id: 5, name: 'Store E'},                                                                           
      { _id: 6, name: 'Store F'}                                                                            
    ],                                                                                                      
    [ { _id: 3, name: 'Store C'} ],                                                                         
    [ { _id: 2, name: 'Store B'} ]                                                                          
  ]                                                                                                         
                                                                                                            
  We wish to simplify this and have just a single array of store info e.g.                                  
  store: [                                                                                                  
    { _id: 5, name: 'Store E'},                                                                             
    { _id: 6, name: 'Store F'},                                                                             
    { _id: 3, name: 'Store C'}                                                                              
    { _id: 2, name: 'Store B'}                                                                              
  ]                                                                                                         
                                                                                                            
  We use the $reduce trick below to do so:                                                                  
    */
    ,{$addFields: {
        store: {$reduce: {
                     input: "$store",
                     initialValue:[],
                         in:{$concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this"]}
                 }}
                }}


]);
```

This yields:

```
{
  _id: '64841d0280a7a74a913b7935',
  subcat: [
    '64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de',
    '64841e2380a7a74a913b7943',
    '6492d31581c81e578307c1f1'
  ],
  store: [
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'Store B'
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: 'Store C'
    },
    {
      _id: 5,
      name: 'Store E'
    },
    {
      _id: 6,
      name: 'Store F'
    }
  ]
}
{
  _id: '6492fd9251feab2f2485a581',
  subcat: [
    '64841e2380a7a74a913b7943',
    '64871d65c82f0e2cb882e4de'
  ],
  store: [
    {
      _id: 4,
      name: 'Store D'
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'Store A'
    }
  ]
}
```