# Query data from multiple mongodb collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

Hi i have a database that have these following collection's

```
db={
  "category": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "Cat A",
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "item": "Cat B",
    },
  ],
  "sticker": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "Sticker 1",
    },
  ],
  "prefix": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "prefix 1",
    },
  ],
  "store": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "Item 1",
      "category_id": "1",
      "sticker_id": "1",
      "prefix_id": "1",
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "item": "Item 2",
      "category_id": "2",
      "sticker_id": "1",
      "prefix_id": "1",
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "item": "Item 3",
      "category_id": "1",
      "sticker_id": "1",
      "prefix_id": "1",
    },
  ],
}
```

and i am using the below query to get the data from mongo collection's

```
await category.aggregate([
{
          $match: {
            _id: 1,
          }
        },
{
          $lookup: {
            "from": "store",
            let: { cid: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$category_id", "$$cid" ]} }},
            ],
            as: "stores"
          }
        }
])
```

with this query i am getting objectId for category, prefix & sticker in response, but i need data along with those objectId, like this

**expected response**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "item": "Cat A",
    "stores": [{
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "item 1",
      "stickerData": {
        "_id": 1,
        "item": "Sticker 1",
      },
      "prefixData": {
        "_id": 1,
        "item": "prefix 1",
      },
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "item": "item 3",
       "stickerData": {
         "_id": 1,
         "item": "Sticker 1",
       },
       "prefixData": {
         "_id": 1,
         "item": "prefix 1",
       },
     },
   ],
  },
]
```

can anybody suggest some proper query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i combine three mongodb query into single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525905/how-can-i-combine-three-mongodb-query-into-single-query)

Comment: Voting to close this as a dupe (more like an extension of the original).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525905/how-can-i-combine-three-mongodb-query-into-single-query/76526273#76526273

Answer (score 0):

In the `$lookup` stage, you must have multiple `$lookup` stages with the pipeline to join *prefix* and *sticker* collections.

Note that your `_id` in both *store*, *prefix*, and *sticker* collections are numeric, while `store_id`, `prefix_id`, and `sticker_id` in the *store* collection were string, make sure that while joining, both ids should be compared as the same type. An example for my query below would convert the `_id` to string.

```
db.category.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 1,
      
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "store",
      let: {
        cid: {
          $toString: "$_id"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$category_id",
                "$$cid"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "sticker",
            let: {
              sticker_id: "$sticker_id"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      {
                        $toString: "$_id"
                      },
                      "$$sticker_id"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            as: "stickerData"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "prefix",
            let: {
              prefix_id: "$prefix_id"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      {
                        $toString: "$_id"
                      },
                      "$$prefix_id"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            as: "prefixData"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            item: 1,
            prefixData: {
              $first: "$prefixData"
            },
            stickerData: {
              $first: "$stickerData"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "stores"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RSH3zO0jDBx)